# Misunderstanding in the Firebase's token verification

Tags: firebase, encryption, cryptography, firebase-authentication, rsa

I want to verify Firebase's token on the server side using [this third party library](https://github.com/pokowaka/jwt-cpp) in the C++. But I have some misunderstanding: 
For the token validation I need to provide public and private keys, [Firebase says that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens):

> Must correspond to one of the public keys listed at
>   https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

But when I opened the link, I could not find public and private keys which I should pass for token verifying.

**So, how can I get public and private keys for token verifying?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the public key to verify a Firebase ID token and jwt in general. That link contains the public keys json object (let's call it publicKeysObject). You get the "kid" field in the JWT header and then get the public key as follows: publicKeysObject[kidFromJWT]

Check the Firebase Admin node.js SDK open sourced implementation for details: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/auth/token-generator.ts

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the delay. Ok, but I have two questions: [Validators need secret keys](https://github.com/pokowaka/jwt-cpp#validating-tokens), if I understood correct, so, what we should to pass as private key? And what we should to do with public key which we will get from `publicKeysObject[kidFromJWT]`? I mean I don't understand this flow: we need to use public key which coincides with kid, e.g. if we have kid "99bf5a385a7babdab5..." then we should use corresponding public key, ok, but with what we need to compare it? Please, add some clarifications in your answer.

Comment: The Gihub repo I included gives you full details how the flow works. Private keys are private. They are not meant to leave the Firebase Auth server. The value of `publicKeysObject[kidFromJWT]` will be the public key to validate the ID token. It is this part: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ...END CERTIFICATE-----\n"  You need the public key and the ID token string to validate its signature. Maybe this library is helpful: https://github.com/madf/jwtxx

Comment: Thanks, I found `jwtxx` more useful for me. Also, now I have another related issue with the Firebase, please, [check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426837/get-users-phone-number-from-c-using-firebase).