# Get user's phone number from C++ using Firebase

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to check user's phone number on the server side with C++. Client side looks ok, but on the server side I can only decode `JWT` from client and find out Firebase ID of the user, but of course this is not what I need.

I still need to know phone number of the user, and I understand that I can do this with user ID and Firebase admin SDK, but I can't find admin SDK for C++ or any web-API which I could use from everywhere. **So, how can I know user's phone number from C++?**

Comment: If you are using phone auth and already can decode the JWT, the `phone_number` is already included in the JWT itself.

Comment: @bojeil indeed! Firebase's JWT already has phone number in the claims, perfect solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Firebase Admin SDK for C++.

What you could do is use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to run the [Admin SDK for Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) on Google's servers and then expose what you need in a [HTTP Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). You can then simply call this URL from your C++ code.

Just be sure to properly secure access to that HTTP endpoint, since otherwise you might be leaking sensitive information.